# Can't play this video error while playing the video in a VideoView

Tags: java, android, vb.net

This my code Don't know what is mistake in this code 
But when i run this activity Can't play this video error is ocured.

```
 package com.example.admin.educationforsocity;

import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import com.example.admin.educationforsocity.R;
public class VideoTutorial extends AppCompatActivity {
    VideoView videoView;
    MediaController mediaController;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_tutorial);
        videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.click);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.ksnn);
                videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
                videoView.start();
                mediaController=new MediaController(VideoTutorial.this);
                videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is the error

Cant play this video

Comment: Your error is only "can't play this video" ? No other informations ? The source of the problem could be a lot of things.

Comment: but 2 days ago i have play the video with the same code and all is working normally

Comment: As a minimum of respect, please begin by answering my questions ... is your error only "can't play this video" ? You don't have any other informations ?

Comment: Yes this is the only error is coming When the activity is running onto the AVD  and my video is not playing

Comment: Do you have some log or any other informations ? If your IDE is giving you one-sentence answer when problem occurs, well it seems to me a really poor IDE.

Comment: But in the code it does not shows any error The Activity is Compiled and run successfully But on the Device this messag is shown

Comment: Unless someone knows this as a recurrent issue, we need to know the following things : what's the path of your video ? What is its file format ? Are you sure you have the permission to read it ? Sadly I can't think I can help you with that, but here are some thoughts about what may be the problem.